# Dropbox anonymous sharing into others own dropbox'?

Tags: file-sharing, dropbox, shared-folders

I know that I can use the "Get link" function of the desktop client to get a link I can send to people so that they can download the files/folders I shared.

I also know I can share a folder in Dropbox in such a way that the person I'm sharing with can get a copy inside their own dropbox, that will be synchronized with my copy, two-way.

Can I sort-of combine the two?

Meaning, is there any way I can get a link that I can publish on my webpage or in a profile here on SU/SO, and let users get a copy of the folder inside their own dropbox, that will mirror and stay in sync with my folder, but not let them add or change any of the content?

I realize that dropbox might not be able to prevent them from actually messing up their local copy, but it could easily be handled by just rewriting the local content with new copies from my original every time that happens.

But, is this possible? Or is the download-from-web type of sharing the only public mass-sharing I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as easy and cross-platform as you want, but for unix users you can try [dropfuse](https://github.com/arekzb/dropfuse).

This does exactly what you want, but must be installed (at least downloaded and executed) on the client side though.